# Does a CUDA stream "become active" after execution of a scheduled host function concludes?

Tags: callback, cuda, cuda-streams, cuda-driver

The CUDA [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gab95a78143bae7f21eebb978f91e7f3f) for scheduling the launching a host function (`cuLaunchHostFunc`) says:

> Completion of the function does not cause a stream to become active except as described above.

I couldn't quite figure out what's "described above". As far as I understand how streams work - the next consecutive piece of work scheduled on the stream after the host function should begin right after the host function execution concludes, i.e. the stream should "become active". Am I missing something? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what being "active" means?